# SQL Joining from 2 fields to a concatenated field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a quote ID field in a table (PING) that has the following format: "XX" (which is just a lead off to the quote number) followed by the USERID "YYYY" and then the Cart_ID "ZZZZ". Both of the second fields come from another table (Cart). I need to join Cart to the first table. These 2 fields are the only way to join them, but I can't figure out how to join 2 fields to 1 field from another table. Obviously code below won't work, but is for illustration.

```
 join PROD..CART on Cart.CART_ID and Cart.USERID = CW_PING.QuoteID
```

Comment: I have added a tag for the RDBMS. It is SQL Server.

Comment: Did you try  `join PROD..CART on Cart.CART_ID + Cart.USERID = CW_PING.QuoteID` to concatenate the values?  The `+` is used to concatenate data in SQL Server.

Comment: I did now and that appears like it will work. How would I account for the "XX" that must be at the front? Am I able to simply say: join PROD..CART on 'XX' + Cart.CART_ID + Cart.USERID = CW_PING.QuoteID

Comment: Try it and see if it works. :)

Comment: I have cast both fields as varchar to match the "XX". It ran through! Just need to figure out what else is wrong. Got no data back. Only the fields in the select statement.

Comment: Is `XX` suppose to be constant for all the records or does it varies? If it varies the you could use [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) to get the value of `XX`

Comment: XX is constant on all of the QuoteID's

Comment: Are YYYY and/or ZZZZ zero-padded? If so, that's probably where the issue lies. Please consider updating your question with the full information, including the fact that `USERID` and `CART_ID` are actually not varchar values, as follows from one of your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the final solution:

`join PROD_QQ..CART on 'QQ' + (right('0000000000' + CAST (Cart.USERID as varchar),4) + (right( '0000000000' + CAST (Cart.CART_ID as varchar),6)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
join PROD..CART on CONCAT(Cart.CART_ID,Cart.USERID) = CW_PING.QuoteID
```

Comment: The `CONCAT()` function will not work in every version of SQL Server.  Are you certain this will work for the OP?

Answer (score -3):

try:

```
join PROD..CART on [Cart.CART_ID + Cart.USERID] = CW_PING.QuoteID
```

Comment: I get invalid column name when I try that.

Comment: The square brackets make this appear to be the actual column name, this would rightfully throw an error.

Comment: Could it be that you meant to use round brackets instead of square ones?

Comment: Yeah, square brackets was a duh.